# lastValueFrom instead of toPromise() why?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

i saw that rxjs will deprecate toPromise(). We should use lastValueFrom instead.
I want to ask what the Reason behind this is?

The Syntax .toPromise() was much more clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic has been covered by several public talks from Ben Lesh about rxjs7. To summarize, `.toPromise()` never really functioned correctly. This is because the response will either be the resolved value, or undefined `<T | undefined>`, which is not how promises work. However, `.lastValueFrom()` will return a promise of type `<T>` or it will throw an empty error if no value is emitted. The added benefit is that `.lastValueFrom()` is configurable and that you can assign the default value should the observable not emit anything.